# Creating raster with circles from dataframe in R

Tags: r, raster, rasterize

How can I create a raster layer with filled circles centered in "c(df$lat,cd$lon)" and radius "df$radius" from a dataframe?

```
df <- data.frame(lat=c(40.4,42.4,42.4,42.4,42.3), 
                 lon=c(-0.3,1,1.5,2.7,2.1), 
                 radius=c(4.4,8.4,11.4,5.4,10.3))

df
#   lat  lon radius
#  40.4 -0.3    4.4
#  42.4  1.0    8.4
#  42.4  1.5   11.4
#  42.4  2.7    5.4
#  42.3  2.1   10.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dismo)
df <- data.frame(lat=c(40.4,42.4,42.4,42.4,42.3), 
                 lon=c(-0.3,1,1.5,2.7,2.1), 
                 radius=c(4.4,8.4,11.4,5.4,10.3))
```

Note the use of lon/lat, not lat/lon

```
p <- df[,2:1]
```

The radius is in meters so your numbers are very small. I'll change them

```
rad <- df[,3]*2500
```

Compute circles

```
cc <- circles(p, rad, lonlat=TRUE, dissolve=FALSE)
plot(cc)
points(p)
```

Get the polygons

```
pls <- polygons(cc)
```

To get a RasterLayer you can either use `predict(cc,  )` or `rasterize(pls,  )`

```
r <- raster(extent(pls), res=.01)
pr <- predict(cc, r)
```

(if you do not want the overlaps to be counted, use `dissolve=TRUE` in the `circles` function)

Comment: That is exactly what I need it. Thank you very much!